# How can I export Apache Solr settings in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, solr, drupal-7

I have selected entity types and bundles in admin/config/search/apachesolr. So is there any way to featurize or export these settings? If it can be done by [Strongram](https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm) module which variable I should use?

Answer (score 0):

Environments created in the apachesolr module are exportable components just like content types or contexts.
Extra variables, like `apachesolr_set_nodeapi_messages` can be exported with Strongarm.